# Multilevel inheritance error C2280: "atttempting to reference a deleted function"

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm making an IRC bot in C++, and it's supposed to react to messages in the IRC channel. The IRC channel belongs to a multiplayer game server, where people can communicate from in-game to IRC and vice versa. (Basically you can see things happening on the server, including chat, without actually having to be in the game).

I have a pretty basic class hierarchy set up to represent gradually more specific types of IRC events.
[Represented on a graph it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbAGv.png)

Now, I'm trying to implement this kind of multi-level inheritance in C++, like this (please excuse my inconsistent styling. I also omitted CIrcCommand because it's very similar to CIngameCommand, and has the same problem)

**CIrcEvent**

```
class CIrcEvent
{
protected:
    EventType m_type;
    
private:
    void(*HandlerFunc)(std::string& nick, std::string& chan, std::vector<std::string>& message);

public:
    CIrcEvent(void(*handler_ptr)(std::string& nick, std::string& chan, std::vector<std::string>& message))
    {
        m_type = EventType::IRCEVENT;
        HandlerFunc = handler_ptr;
    }
};
```

**CCommand**

```
class CCommand : public CIrcEvent
{
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_level;

public:
    std::string& GetCommandName() { return this->m_name; }
    int GetLevel() { return this->m_level; }
};
```

**CIngameCommand**

```
class CIngameCommand : public CCommand
{
public:
    CIngameCommand(std::string& CmdName, int CmdLevel, void(*CmdFuncPointer)(std::string& nick, std::vector<std::string>& message))
    {
        m_type = EventType::IGCMD;
        m_name = CmdName;
        m_level = CmdLevel;
        HandlerFunc = CmdFuncPointer;
    }

    void Call(std::string& nick, std::vector<std::string>& message) { HandlerFunc(nick, message); }

private:
    void(*HandlerFunc)(std::string& nick, std::vector<std::string>& message);
};
```

But inside of class CIngameCommand's constructor's definition...

```
CIngameCommand(std::string& CmdName, int CmdLevel, void(*CmdFuncPointer)(std::string& nick, std::vector<std::string>& message))
{ // <-- error on this line
    m_type = EventType::IGCMD;
```

... I get a C2280 error.

```
IRCCommand.h(63): error C2280: 'CCommand::CCommand(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
IRCCommand.h(43): note: compiler has generated 'CCommand::CCommand' here
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am aware that I haven't defined a custom constructor for CCommand class, but that's because as opposed to all the others, I'm only planning to use CCommand's derived classes (CIngameCommand and CIrcCommand), I'm never going to use it on its own.

What can I do to circumvent this error? Is my design flawed? If so, how can I implement this differently?

Comment: What is `EventType `?  And `CIrcEvent` is not default constructable as you have defined a constructor for it, so the default is deleted

Comment: It's an enum representing the kind of message (and therefore which class it belongs to), basically.  enum EventType { IRCCMD, IGCMD, IRCEVENT };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deleted function is the default constructor of `CIrcEvent`. It has a user defined constructor and then that constructor has to be called from the derived class.

You don't define any constructors in `CCommand` so *"compiler has generated 'CCommand::CCommand'"*. Such a compiler generated constructor will also call the base class' default constructor - but the base class doesn't have one!